# Detokenising multiple files using msbuild - property not found error

Tags: msbuild

I have the following piece of code to replace all tokens in a given set of files:
(I'm using the msbuild extensions detokenise task).

```
 <Project DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
        <UsingTask TaskName="MSBuild.ExtensionPack.FileSystem.Detokenise" AssemblyFile="Extensions/MSBuild.ExtensionPack.dll"/>

        <PropertyGroup>
            <someValueToReplace>New Value</someValueToReplace>
        </PropertyGroup>

        <ItemGroup>
            <TextFiles Include="test1.txt"/>
            <TextFiles Include="test2.txt"/>
        </ItemGroup>

        <Target Name="Build">
            <Detokenise TaskAction="Detokenise" TextEncoding="ASCII" TargetFiles="@(TextFiles)"/>
        </Target>

    </Project>
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:
(I don't get this error if only one item exist in the ItemGroup).
(Note that I don't want to explicitly inject the tokens that I want replaced).

"C:\Users\v\Desktop\msbuildSample\detokenise.xml" (default target) (1) ->
(Build target) ->
  C:\Users\v\Desktop\msbuildSample\detokenise.xml(10,3): error : Property not found: toReplace
  C:\Users\v\Desktop\msbuildSample\detokenise.xml(10,3): error : ArgumentException: Review error log\r
C:\Users\v\Desktop\msbuildSample\detokenise.xml(10,3): error :

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake .. I thought it was a bug in msbuild .. actually the issue was exactly what the error message indicated -- I was trying to replace a variable called toReplace -- but it wasn't defined.